# C# Open source library for reading and writing swf file,which supports version 8,9 and 10

Tags: c#, .net, flash, actionscript-3

Currently I am using SWFDOTNET libray for reading and writing swf file,which supports swf file from version 1 to 7.

Is there any other open C# source lib for reading and writing swf flash which supports swf file version 8,9 and 10?

Answer (score 0):

Well [Swf.Net](http://swf.codeplex.com/) supports up to version 8. Their site says they plan on support versions 9 and 10 but the last release was in 2008, and last change set was in 2010.

I didn't see any other libraries for c# during my search...

Answer (score 0):

Try [GOA project](http://goaproject.sourceforge.net/) - it supports version 9+ also.

I am using it in recent years since 2005.

Comment: Could you provide just a bit more information?  For example, what class is used to read an SWF file, what class is used to write one?  The site you linked to doesn't appear to have documentation.